# /Users/homedir/.zshrc:export:1: not valid in this context: Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin

Tags: visual-studio-code, homebrew, zshrc

After installing Homebrew natively in Mac silicon, I get the following message (macOS Big Sur) when I open zsh terminal.

```
/home/dir/.zshrc:export:1: not valid in this context: Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
```

following the docs from VScode, I did the following:

```
cat << EOF >> ~/.zprofile
# Add Visual Studio Code (code)
export PATH="\$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"
EOF

my .zshrc file as follows:

export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin
```

when I type code . in my zsh terminal the following message is display.

```
zsh: command not found: code
```

Any help will be appreciated thanks.

Comment: The line in your .zshrc is wrong; it should be `export PATH="$PATH:/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/bin"`. You should also check .zprofile to make sure it has the line right (from the command you have, it should've been added correctly).